# SharedPreferences changes triggers FileObserver's create event every time

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have implemented a custom class which extends FileObserver class and I am listening for the events in the shared_prefs directory of my app's internal storage. The problem is every time I perform the following operation:

```
this.getSharedPreferences("fs_myfilename_", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("Default", "value" + System.currentTimeMillis()).apply();
```

`FileObserver.CREATE`, `FileObserver.MODIFY` & `FileObserver.DELETE` events along with others as well.

My question is why does the above operation triggers all the events simultaneously? I am expecting that the first time when we perform the write operation we should get the `FileObserver.CREATE` event and on subsequent operations we should get the `FileObserver.MODIFY` event in the `onEvent` method of `FileObserver` class.

Any answers will be appreciated.

UPDATE:

Code:

```
 public SharedPrefObserver(String path) { // This class extends FileObserver class
        super(path);  
  }

  mSharedPrefObserver = new SharedPrefObserver(getContext().getDataDir() + "/shared_prefs");
  mSharedPrefObserver.startWatching();
```

```
@Override
public void onEvent(int event, @Nullable String path) {

    if (event == FileObserver.DELETE || event == FileObserver.CREATE || event == FileObserver.MODIFY) {

        Log.e(TAG, "Types of event: \n" +
                "1. Create: " + FileObserver.CREATE + "\n" +
                "2. Modify: " + FileObserver.MODIFY + "\n" +
                "3. Delete: " + FileObserver.DELETE + "\n"
        );

        Log.e(TAG, "onEvent called for the event: " + event + "\n" + "path: " + path);          
    }
}
```

Logs of the event (Currently, I am only listening to CREATE, MODIFY & DELETE events)

```
2023-10-13 05:50:27.161  2867-2953  SharedPrefObserver      com.example.app          E  Types of event:  
                                                                                                    1. Create: 256
                                                                                                    2. Modify: 2
                                                                                                    3. Delete: 512                                                                                           
2023-10-13 05:50:27.160  2867-2953  SharedPrefObserver      com.example.app           E  onEvent called for the event: 256
                                                                                                    path: fs_myfilename_.xml
2023-10-13 05:50:27.161  2867-2953  SharedPrefObserver      com.example.app          E  Types of event: 
                                                                                                    1. Create: 256
                                                                                                    2. Modify: 2
                                                                                                    3. Delete: 512
2023-10-13 05:50:27.161  2867-2953  SharedPrefObserver      com.example.app          E  onEvent called for the event: 2
                                                                                                    path: fs_myfilename_.xml

2023-10-13 05:50:27.172  2867-2953  SharedPrefObserver      com.example.app          E  Types of event: 
                                                                                                    1. Create: 256
                                                                                                    2. Modify: 2
                                                                                                    3. Delete: 512
2023-10-13 05:50:27.172  2867-2953  SharedPrefObserver      com.example.app          E  onEvent called for the event: 512
                                                                                                    path: fs_myfilename_.xml.bak
```

Comment: first time I'd expect create & maybe modify. Not sure why delete. Can you share more code of how you are observing? and the log of the events being observed?

Comment: @Blundell I have added the logs

Comment: @Blundell I understand that delete event is being triggerd for a temporary file. But what I am not able to understand is why CREATE event is triggered every time I modify the SharedPreference file.  Does putString  or apply function creates new file after every modifcation?

Comment: Not from what I know, what does the log look like if you update a couple of different prefs in different orders? I can't imagine it deletes the whole file just to update one value. Sorry I'm not much help